# How to add new objects

Tags: c#, class, object

Today i am trying to add another info into a class but i am unable to add. I have tough of adding another class but i am sure that there is a way to modify the class to add more Info.

The info i want to add is 
Mr Chan, 1200, 18 Pioneer Rd and 
Mr Lee, 600, Blk 21 #21-21 Yishun Rd

```
class PersonalInfo
{
    private string name;
    private float salary;
    private string address;

    public  PersonalInfo(string nameVar, float salaryVar, string addressVar)
    {
        name = nameVar;
        salary = salaryVar;
        address = addressVar;
    }

    public void PrintPersonalInfo(TextBox txtPersonalInfo)
    {
        txtPersonalInfo.Text += name + Environment.NewLine + salary + Environment.NewLine + address + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

That is my code for the class Personal info.

```
 private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PersonalInfo obj = new PersonalInfo("Mr Tan", 3000, "Blk 123, #12-003 Kepple Rd");

        obj.PrintPersonalInfo(txtPersonalinfo);
```

That is my code for the form.cs So far i can only think of adding new class to add more Info. Now i would like to know how to modify PersonalInfo.cs to add more Info.

Thanks for all you help and have a nice day ahead :)

Comment: I suggest you look up basic OO guides/tutorials. Specifically about properties and fields.

Comment: You mean, add more properties, or modify them, for example:

You want to modify name and change it from "Mr Tan" to "Mr Tan2" ?
Or you want to ADD properties to the class:

You have name, salary and adress, you want to ad MORE in runtime?

Comment: I would like to add more info @c_str

Comment: @YongJunRunWhat do you mean by add?
You mean EDIT the existing information?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider encapsulating your common properties into a new object, say `BasicInfo`:

```
public class BasicInfo
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public float Salary {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    // add more properties when necessary
    // e.g. Gender
    // public string Gender {get; set;}
}
```

With that, in the constructor of `PersonalInfo` class, you can just pass in a `BasicInfo` object so you don't have to worry about all those properties in the `PersonalInfo` constructor.

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
    BasicInfo basicInfo;
    public PersonalInfo(BasicInfo basicInfo)
    {
        this.basicInfo =  basicInfo;
    }
}
```

You can then keep adding new properties into your `BasicInfo` class without needing to change `PersonalInfo` constructor. Hopefully it helps and that's what you are looking for.

Comment: err... down vote? perhaps I misunderstood your question?